# How to change label color in vb.net using codes?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to change the color of a label using its code, something like:

```
dim r as color
r = color.red
```

How do I use or assign that code to a label from a button...? Like in my form button and a label.. when the button is clicked the label changes its color .. how do I do that in vb.net?.

Here is my button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim r As Color
        r = Color.Red

    End Sub

End Class
```

??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined a variable which is not the right way to do it.
A label exposes some properties and to achieve your goal you simply do this:

```
 Label1.BackColor = Color.Aqua
```

Comment: It changes background color, i though you want to change text color?

Comment: Im not sure to understand what do you mean. Are you mean that you want to change text color? In that particular case you need to use ForeColor property in order to achieve your goal. In example **Label1.ForeColor=Color.Red**. That's It
Each Label object expose several options that you can manipulate as per your need. Just try which one you need to use or change and see result :) Best regards

Answer (score 3):

Use BackColor property

```
label1.BackColor=Color.Red
```

Answer (score 1):

First 
add the following import statement to the top of your class

```
    Imports System.Drawing
```

Then use this code

```
   label1.BackColor=Color.Red
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to set dim you can just use `forecolor` property.

in button_1 write this code:

```
   Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Aqua
    End Sub 
End class
```

`Label1.ForeColor = Color.Aqua`
Here  `color.color_name` you can use any color you want

now when you click on `button_1` and the  `label.1` text color get changed.